# If an application is not closed (running in background) , does it cause application crash?

Tags: android

I have an application works well in emulator and mobile but if we  close the application by clicking on exit button of the phone(not from application).and after few hours we are reopening the  application, it gets opened from middle of the application(not from the first screen).and after using that app some times it gets hanged and message is displayed 'unfortunately app has stopped '. Is this mobile problem or application problem.

Comment: please add code in your question

Comment: Atleast you should post cat log for error log..

Comment: ya thats true , but its working fine in emulator,and some times(rarely) i am getting this message in mobile.so i cannot see logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) documentation.
The Android OS has its own application lifecycle management.
Each activity is kept "alive" until its onDestroy is called. For example, the OS can keep an activity alive for several hours and then kill it when there is not enough memory to perform other tasks.

What happens in you case is most likely that the same activity re-runs when you open you app again (in the emulator the activity is probably killed before) and you're in a bad state since probably some of the objects were disposed or re-initialized.

The right thing to do is use some of the other state callbacks, such as onPause/Resume to allocate/dispose resources used by the activity.

You code might look like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity
{
     public void onCreate()
     {
         super.onCreate();
         // Do some object initialization
         // You might assume that this code is called each time the activity runs.
         // THIS CODE WILL RUN ONLY ONCE UNTIL onDestroy is called.
         // The thing is that you don't know when onDestry is called even if you close the.
         // Use this method to initialize layouts, static objects, singletons, etc'.    
     }

     public void onDestroy()
     {
         super.onDestroy();
         // This code will be called when the activity is killed.
         // When will it be killed? you don't really know in most cases so the best thing to do 
         // is to assume you don't know when it be killed.
     }
}
```

Your code should look something like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity
{
     public void onCreate()
     {
         super.onCreate();
         // Initialize layouts
         // Initialize static stuff which you want to do only one time  
     }

     public void onDestroy()
     {
         // Release stuff you initialized in the onCreate
     }

     public void onResume()
     {
         // This method is called each time your activity is about to be shown to the user,        
         // either since you moved back from another another activity or since your app was re-
         // opened.
     }

     public void onPause()
     {
         // This method is called each time your activity is about to loss focus.
         // either since you moved to another activity or since the entire app goes to the 
         // background.
     }

}
```

bottom line: always assume the same activity can re-run again.

Comment: could you please give me an example on " The right thing to do is use some of the other state callbacks, such as onPause/Resume to allocate/dispose resources used by the activity. "

Comment: Sure, take a look on the answer. Just did some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that particular application is not closed properly. It is application error only.

Comment: could you please tell me how to close application properly ?

Comment: You have to close the application from exit button or back button. Then only the application is closed properly. You can check it in Task Manager whether the application is still running.